# Why is the padding of sibling element affecting where this element is rendered?

Tags: html, css

In the following SSCCE<sup>1</sup>, if `padding-top` is not applied to `.first-page`, both `.first-page` and `first-page-sibling` are rendered as expected. But when I apply this CSS property to `.first-page`, its sibling element, i.e. `.first-page-siblineg` seems to go down by the number of pixels which is the value of `padding-top` applied on `.first-page`.

The question is why? What am I doing wrong?

```css
.first-page-wrapper {
    height:100%;
}

.first-page {
    width:90%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:yellow;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-top:120px;
}

.first-page-sibling {
    height:100%;
    width:25px;
    background-color:red;
    border:3px solid blue;
    display:inline-block;
}

/**************************************/

html, body {
 height:100%;
}

.first-page {
 height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-page-wrapper">    
    <div class="first-page">.</div> <!-- .first-page -->  
    <div class="first-page-sibling">.</div>
</div><!-- .first-page-wrapper -->

     <p style="background-color:pink; opacity:0.5;">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.., comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
     
        The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
        
     Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.., comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
     
     The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
     
     There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which dont look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isnt anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>
```

---

1. "Short Self-Contained Correct/Compilable Example," also known as an "MCVE" ([Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `first-page` and `first-page-sibling` are inline-blocks, so they share the same baseline by default (the initial value of `vertical-align` is `baseline`).
So when you move one down by adding some padding at the top, the other one obeys the baseline and moves down too.

Solution: assign `vertical-align:top` to them both; then they will share the same top edge instead.

```css
.first-page-wrapper {
    height:100%;
}

.first-page {
    width:90%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:yellow;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-top:120px;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.first-page-sibling {
    height:100%;
    width:25px;
    background-color:red;
    border:3px solid blue;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}

/**************************************/

html, body {
 height:100%;
}

.first-page {
 height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-page-wrapper">    
    <div class="first-page">.</div> <!-- .first-page -->  
    <div class="first-page-sibling">.</div>
</div><!-- .first-page-wrapper -->

     <p style="background-color:pink; opacity:0.5;">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.., comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
     
        The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
        
     Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.., comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
     
     The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
     
     There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which dont look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isnt anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>
```

Comment: Hey, if the downvoter can explain their downvote, maybe we can work out some kind of compromise that will get you your rep point back.

Comment: Who is downvoting the answers I am upvoting? =/ I am upvoting them because they work.

Comment: Hi, firstly thank you indeed for your time and answer. I did upvote it. And this answer was the first, and very helpful answer (as it explains the reason in addition to the solution) so I should accept it. But Ronen Cypis also answered correctly, and they have fewer votes, and they asked in comments, so if you don't care much about votes, do you mind if I mark their answer as the accepted one?

Comment: I do care about votes! (Otherwise I wouldn't have posted my comment to the downvoter.) But I firmly believe you should accept whatever answer helps you best. Based on what you need, what you can use, not on moral considerations like "who hit Post Your Answer first" or "who can use the points the most".

Comment: Thank you, and I agree. Marking this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Use `box-sizing: border-box`. If you don't use it, the size of the box will be `100% + 120px`. With border-box, the total width will be calculated since the border of the box.

Vertical-align helps you too

```css
.first-page-wrapper {
    height:100%;
}

.first-page {
    width:90%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:yellow;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-top:120px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.first-page-sibling {
    height:100%;
    width:25px;
    background-color:red;
    border:3px solid blue;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

/**************************************/

html, body {
 height:100%;
}

.first-page {
 height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-page-wrapper">    
    <div class="first-page">.</div> <!-- .first-page -->  
    <div class="first-page-sibling">.</div>
</div><!-- .first-page-wrapper -->

     <p style="background-color:pink; opacity:0.5;">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.., comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
     
        The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
        
     Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.., comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
     
     The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
     
     There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which dont look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isnt anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>
```

Comment: Not exactly, see the yellow box. I update the answer with an improvement. This is a complete answer because the yellow box has the correct height and width

Comment: It didn't work when I posted that comment. It works now after the imrovement. Thank you for your time and explanatory answer. =)

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align:top;` to your `.first-page` div will solve it.

As the default value for `vertical-align` property for divs is `baseline`. your `.first-page` and `.firs-page-sibling` are aligned on their baseline, when in your case, you want their "top" to be aligned.

```css
.first-page-wrapper {
    height:100%;
}

.first-page {
    width:90%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:yellow;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-top:120px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.first-page-sibling {
    height:100%;
    width:25px;
    background-color:red;
    border:3px solid blue;
    display:inline-block;
}

/**************************************/

html, body {
 height:100%;
}

.first-page {
 height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-page-wrapper">    
    <div class="first-page">.</div> <!-- .first-page -->  
    <div class="first-page-sibling">.</div>
</div><!-- .first-page-wrapper -->

     <p style="background-color:pink; opacity:0.5;">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.., comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
     
        The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
        
     Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.., comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
     
     The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
     
     There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which dont look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isnt anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>
```

Comment: Who is downvoting the answers I am upvoting? =/ I am upvoting them because they work.

Comment: I don't know... down  vote with no explanation is just stupid :-)
If it helped you, you should accept it as the correct answer then...

Comment: I want to accept your answer because you have fewer votes than Mr. Lister, and I always feel inclined to be nicer to people with fewer votes (because I can relate to them) =P, but you should see the answer by Mr. Lister and Marcos Perez Gude, they have explained the reasons for why that didn't work and why this works. It is this kind of answers which are the most useful, for me as well as for future visitors. You can learn from them. I'll think about accepting answer for the few minutes left, and try to be fair. =) Thank you very much again for your time and answer.

Comment: I agree. adding explanation.

Comment: You can see comments under the answer of Mr Lister, and they are cent percent right. Hopefully you will have many of your answers as accepted in future. =) Thank you again.